# LINQ to SQL returning old data after an update

Tags: c#, .net, linq, linq-to-sql, linq-to-entities

I have an app that uses LINQ to SQL to connect to database. I have a problem getting LINQ to SQL to return correct new update data.

What happened is that, I changed a field on UI, LINQ to SQL generated update statement, and stored the new data in database. However, LINQ to SQL keeps returning the old data after that, I have to stop and restart IIS to get the new updated data.

**Update**

Please note that the old data is returned from LINQ to SQL.

Any idea?

Comment: did you commit your changes after the update?

Comment: @Adrian The data must be being saved if when the app is restarted, the new data is returned.

Comment: then maybe you're caching the data and it returns the cached values not the fresh ones

Comment: Please don't just add ", C#, .NET" and such to your titles. Please use the tags for that.

Comment: What's the lifetime of the `DataContext` you're using? It sounds like you might be reusing it [for more than one "unit of work"](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.linq.datacontext.aspx)

Comment: Alternatively, multiple `DataContexts` might be sharing a cache.  Turning off object tracking can help there.  See 'Second DataContext is not Updated' [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/Bb386929(v=vs.100).aspx).

Comment: @Sean U, thanks, your answered the question. Please open the answer so I can mark it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Because of the way Linq to SQL handles caching, there are two situations that can cause odd behavior:

1. Reuse of `DataContext`.  `DataContext` is meant to be used for one "unit of work", where a "unit of work" is essentially the shortest amount of time you can get away with letting the `DataContext` live.  See the Remarks section on the [MSDN page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.linq.datacontext.aspx).
2. Multiple `DataContext`s. They will maintain separate caches, so changes made using one `DataContext` may not be reflected in data being retrieved from others.  You can turn off caching by setting `ObjectTrackingEnabled`, which will brute-force fix the issue.  Otherwise, some techniques for managing concurrent `DataContexts` are described here: [How to: Manage Change Conflicts](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb399389.aspx)

Comment: the second point, multiple datacontext should be able to have the correct data. Could you elaborate on this?

Comment: Not in any depth; I'm not terribly informed on all the details. I believe it's just the standard caching/consistency conundrum, though: A cache can't know if the data in the DB has changed without polling it on every query, and doing that would defeat the purpose of having a cache.

Answer (score 0):

This sounds like you are using some sort of caching, maybe page caching? If the only way you can retrieve the updated data is by restarting the application, then your data must be application lifetime dependent.

Comment: Please note that the old data is returned from LINQ to SQL.

Comment: Are you sure? Have you stepped through the code with a debugger to see whether the LINQ to SQL is being called? If so, can you post the code that is returning the stale data please.